# Cache (static) content from other website on my own webserver

Tags: php, caching, apache2

My website is loading slowly and I ran this test: http://www.webpagetest.org/result/120227_MD_3CQZM/1/performance_optimization/

Which indicates that files stored on gametrackers.com is not being cached.
Apache and joomla already cache content that is on my server.

I'm using a script from gametrackers.com to show my teamspeak 3 statistics on my website[1](http://www.xgclan.com)
However this script sometimes loads slowly duo to issues with gametrackers.com server and that's why I'd like to store a copy of it on my own webserver as cache and refresh it every 30 minutes from the gametrackers website.

If the gametrackers website is down(which is quite common) it should keep the last successful cache check.

How would I do this with apache 2.4.1 and possibly php?

If its possible I'd also like to use css sprites because webpagetest.org indicates:

```
The following images served from gametracker.com should be combined into as few images as possible using CSS sprites.

http://cache.www.gametracker.com/images/components/html0/gt_icon.gif
http://cache.www.gametracker.com/images/components/html0/online.gif
http://cache.www.gametracker.com/images/flags/nl.gif
http://cache.www.gametracker.com/images/game_icons/ts3.png
http://cache.www.gametracker.com/images/server_info/16x16_channel_green.png
http://cache.www.gametracker.com/images/server_info/16x16_player_off.png
http://cache.www.gametracker.com/images/server_info/vs_tree_item.gif
http://cache.www.gametracker.com/images/server_info/vs_tree_last.gif
http://cache.www.gametracker.com/images/server_info/vs_tree_outer.gif
http://www.gametracker.com/images/game_icons/ts3.png
```

Answer (score 1):

CSS Sprites are a concept image resource where you use one image with several icons and other items positioned so you can with only one request load several images.

If the images aren´t on your site, it will be very difficult to implement that, and to do so you need strict patterns.

Check: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/04/27/the-mystery-of-css-sprites-techniques-tools-and-tutorials/

If you have a vps / dedicated server you can use [mod_pagespeed](http://code.google.com/intl/pt-BR/speed/page-speed/docs/module.html) it does several combination of things that web site optimizers like, automatically.

But don´t just believe that web site optimizers and testing tools like that are accurate.

They just suggest measures that could help, some practical, some don´t.

Good luck.

Comment: Unfornutely mod_pagespeed does not work for apache on windows.

But maybe the caching of a different website could be done by setting up apache as a proxy? I don't have any experience with this but I've heard its possible.